# I know the truth

Tags: riddle, steganography

Firstly, I am one word long.

Secondly, you will need the first three things.

You'll need a handful of guesses to figure out what I am.

But even if I tell you, I might be lying, mate!

Hint:

> If you can't figure me out, you're a very unlucky person.

Hint 2:

> Pay attention to one of the tags!

Hint 3:

> Every clue and hint has a hidden element, except for this one <s>and the footer</s>.

Hint 4:

> Until the end, don't worry about the things three, for you won't need them.

Hint 5 (big hint):

> This riddle apparently needs five (or eleven) handfuls of guesses. How many is that? Use [math](/questions/tagged/math).

---

<s><sup>1</sup> Yes, this is a clue, please don't close as too broad. :)</s>

Deleted, this caused too much confusion as people thought this was a clue.

Edited Clue 5

Comment: My first non-Riley puzzle!

Comment: Congrats . I hope others will follow the same suit

Comment: Um a handful of guesses? That seems like a red flag to flag for "too broad"

Comment: It's a clue, you shouldn't actually need a handful of guesses. :)

Comment: Oh okay. I was panicking for a sec :P

Comment: I don't think this is neccesarily steganography, since steganography is directly hiding something within a text (like say if I wrote "Sock the eating apple leaves, which taking the first letters reveals STEAL). Now I don't know your full riddle, but I think it can be just tagged riddle. Of course, I don't know what your riddle hides, so I might be wrong.

Comment: I decline to respond to that comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76128/discussion-between-north-and-oldbunny2800).

Comment: I added a hint.

Comment: Another hint in the game!

Comment: Should I post the answer or more hints?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are a

> Fib

Because

> In the first line: First followed by "one" -> 1 1 
>  
>  Second ... three -> 2 3
>  
>  A handful is -> 5
>  
>  I may be lying mate -> m ate -> eight -> 8
>  
>  Unlucky -> 13
>  
>  Hint (2) "(to one) of the tags" -> 21
>  
>  hint (4) "three, for" -> 34
>  
>  Hint (5) "five (or eleven) handfuls (a handful is 5 so eleven handfuls is 5 * 11 = 55" or five handfuls is 5 5 = 55. The big hint is to use "math" which is a hint that we are talking about a mathematical concept, in this case a sequence.
>  
>  1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55...etc is the fibonacci sequence.
>  Take the first 3 letters, and we get "Fib" which is "one word", and a "lie"

Comment: You’re so close! There’s another step though.

Comment: I added a bit more for the hints, and changed the final solution to include one more step

Comment: This is the correct answer! Look a bit more into hint 5 before I give you the check mark.

Comment: Does this help? Or is there still something missing?

Comment: Correct! Congratulations!

Comment: 5 handfuls == 55? I like "wand" better.

Answer (score 4):

Are you a

> Wand?

One Word Long,

> Wand is one word long!

Handful of guesses,

> Handful of guesses to figure out the correct spell

But even if I tell you, I might be lying, mate!

> The Wand Card in tarot cards. They predict, but prediction can be wrong.

The Hint,

> The wand card is the considered to be of Good luck. Hence not getting it could mean one is unlucky

you will need the first three things.

> Don't know about this one. Could be a Harry Potter Reference.

Comment: Good guess, but no. Try reading the clues more carefully!

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Abracadabra

Firstly, I am one word long.

> It is a long word

Secondly, you will need the first three things.

> It contains the first three letters of the alphabet (A,B,C)

You'll need a handful of guesses to figure out what I am.

But even if I tell you, I might be lying, mate!

> I'll address these two together;  'Abracadabra' is a  word stereo-typically used by magicians during "tricks".   There is deceit going on (misdirection), guessing how they did it.

Comment: That’s a good guess, but not the answer. Pay attention to the tags

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> One (like the number/word)

Firstly, I am one word long.

> Well, it's one, it's the length of the word one. That's why the sentence is oddly worded.

Secondly, you will need the first three things.

> First three things... three letters.

You'll need a handful of guesses^1 to figure out what I am.

> A handful of guesses, and then one. (this might be overthinking kicking in but maybe not.)

But even if I tell you, I might be lying, mate!

> Well, this seems to be a play on "I" being like a "1"?

Hint 1:

> A play off of how the number one is in every part of everyday life, so it's unlucky if you don't see it?

Hint 2:

> Pay attention to *ONE* of the tags. Here's one again.

I could be completely wrong here though.

---

Another guess:

Are you

> Familial

Firstly, I am one word long.

> Familial is one word long

Secondly, you will need the first three things.

> I unscrambled all the third words without the hints and it came out to this.

You'll need a handful of guesses^1 to figure out what I am.

> It's a word that rarely is used.

But even if I tell you, I might be lying, mate!

> Maybe just something to show you the "if"

Hint 1:

> If you don't have a family (familiar means relating to or having the characteristics of a family; "children of the same familial background"), you're viewed as unlucky.

Hint 2:

> This tells you to look at the steganography.

This is also probably incorrect.

Comment: Hello, nice to see you here! Sorry, this answer is wrong. Just so you know, like Hint 3 says, the footer doesn't matter, but otherwise those were pretty good guesses!

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I didn't notice the third hint...

Comment: I added a new idea!

Comment: Good guess, but no. Look deeper!

Answer (score 0):

Just a trial :)

Firstly, I am one word long.

> This could refer to the marked (with 1) word **guesses**

Secondly, you will need the first three things.

> The first 3 things of guesses are **gue**. Gue is the sound of a **dove**. 
>
>  #Could also be a small hint of "new, old and borrowed"

You'll need a handful of guesses1 to figure out what I am.

> This could mean multiple doves. Multiple doves are mostly a sign of a **marriage**.

But even if I tell you, I might be lying, mate!

> A marriage can also go through a divorce.

Hint:

> If you can't figure me out, you're a very unlucky person.
>
>  
>  Some people might think if you're not married you're unlucky. Mostly the ones that are not married.

**Another idea:**

Firstly, I am one word long.

> **F**irstly, the first character

Secondly, you will need the first three things.

> S**e**condly, the second character

You'll need a handful of guesses1 to figure out what I am.

> Here we have to guess so I take **a**

But even if I tell you, I might be lying, mate!

> **l**ying

The Hint:

> If you can't figure me out, you're a very unlucky person. 
>
>
>  If you cant figure out what feal means your very unlucky.

Comment: Good guess, but this is not the answer.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 I added another idea and ty :)

Comment: Sorry, no. Good try!

Answer (score 0):

Is this

> TRUTH

Firstly, I am one word long.

Secondly, you will need the first three things.

> I know the **Truth**

You'll need a handful of guesses1 to figure out what I am.

> Like what you said, this means that we don't really need a handfull of guesses because I already know the Truth. Although I don't have an idea with the correlation of the superscript 1.

But even if I tell you, I might be lying, mate!

> If youre not lying then it means you're telling us the truth.

Comment: Good guess, but no. By the way, the footnote is not part of the riddle.

Comment: I see. I'm new here, what if I have another answer? Should I edit this answer or post new one? Or is it a game over for me?

Comment: You can definitely make another guess. Either option is fine.

Actually, edit: Meta consensus says you should make a new post, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I’ll give it a try:

> Flatulence

```
Firstly, I am one word long.
```

> My solution is one word long.

```
Secondly, you will need the first three things.
```

> The first letters of the first three words of »**F**irstly, **I** **a**m one word long.« are F, I (uppercase i which could be read as lowercase l) and a: FLA(tulence).

```
You'll need a handful of guesses to figure out what I am.
```

> guesses should be read as »gasses«. You may need this mixture of gasses to medically figure out what type of flatulence it is.

```
But even if I tell you, I might be lying, mate!
```

> If tell (on) you, I may be lying. If I say it was you, it may actually have been me. Whoever smelled it dealt it.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem very convincing to me. Especially the transition from capital i to lower-case L and from guesses to gasses, which aren't clued at all in the question. Welcome to the site though! :-)

Comment: This is funny, but sadly not the correct answer.